# Calling a method on a method c++

Tags: c++, return-type

```
list_sorter add(std::list<typeOfList> &list){
    list_num++;
    lp.insert(lp.end(), list.begin(), list.end());
    lp.sort();
    list.clear();
    std::cout << list_num << std::endl;
    return *this;}
```

I have this little method in a class template, in the main I call it like this:

```
si.add(lc).add(lb);
```

Both times it does get executed, it couts an increased list_num, but after the second add() it doesn't get saved. Why is that?

Comment: Change the return type from `list_sort` to `list_sort&`

Comment: Step through in your debugger and watch what `this` is. As a note, this style with `x().y().z()` is called "chaining".

Answer (score 2):

`add` returns by value, that means it'll return a new temporary `list_sorter` copied from `*this`, and the temporary has nothing to do with the original object.

You can change it to return-by-reference. i.e.

```
list_sorter& add(std::list<typeOfList> &list){
    list_num++;
    lp.insert(lp.end(), list.begin(), list.end());
    lp.sort();
    list.clear();
    std::cout << list_num << std::endl;
    return *this;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Well that was easy. I should had knew, I'm new to c++, it takes time to get used to references/pointers.

Answer (score 0):

```
list_sorter add(std::list<typeOfList> &list) {
    ...
    return *this;
}
```

Since this function returns a value and not a reference, it modifies the object, then returns *a copy* of the object.  The subsequent call occurs on the copy. Afterwards, that copy is destroyed, since you never assigned it to a variable.

Solution is:

```
list_sorter& add(std::list<typeOfList> &list)
           ^
```

Comment: Thanks! References/pointers always fool me. I will be more careful next time.